# $X,Y$ complete metric spaces, $f:X \to Y$ continuous, Show that $f$ is closed(under certain circumstances)

Tags: general-topology

> Say $X,Y$ are complete metric spaces, and $f: X \to Y$ is continuous.
>
> Also, say that for every Cauchy sequence $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset f[X]$ there exist a Cauchy sequence  $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset X$ such that $f(x_n)=y_n$.
>
> Show that $f$ is closed.

It is very easy to prove that $f[X]$ is closed, but I couldn't figure out how to prove it for every closed $A \subset X$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Apparently this isn't true. *Robert Israel* gives a counterexample in the answers section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true.  Consider $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by 
$$ f(x) = \cases{x & for $x \le 1$\cr
                 1/x & for $x > 1$\cr}$$
This is not closed because e.g. $f([1,\infty)) = (0,1]$ is not closed.
But the condition on $y_n$ and $x_n$ is satisfied, e.g. by $x_n = y_n$.

Comment: You are right! Ha... I guess it isn't true.
Thank you